# Is "true" (lower case) already a keyword in visual studio? Can it be overridden?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2005, boolean, keyword, c89

I am using the visual studio 2005 C++ compiler (but are coding using C89 type ANSI C) and am unable to define a "true" and "false" keyword to use as follows:

```
#define true 1
#define false 0
```

I have used this exact code successfully using the Green Hills C++ compiler, but visual studio behaves as if "true" and "false" are already keywords. Is this true? Can I override them with my own definition, and if so how?

With using the lines above I get C2143 errors during compilation for lines such as:

```
someFuntion(someVar,otherVar,true);
```

I have already made certain the other types match the function definition and if I change the true to a "1" or "0x1" the errors go away.

Comment: The problem was not with the definition but with a syntax error. I had incorrectly used the following:    #define true 1;
    #define false 0;  The semicolons caused the problem. If you would like to expound upon why I will up vote your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `true` and `false` are never a C keyword, not even in C99/C11. C99 introduced native boolean type `_Bool` but `true` and `false` are still just macros for `1` and `0` respectively defined in `stdbool.h`

There's no reference that Visual Studio defines the macro `true` or `false`, but you can always use this:

```
#ifndef true
#define true 1
#endif
#ifndef false
#define false 0
#endif
```